# Custom styles getting overrided by salesforce default CSS after rerendeing

Tags: apex, css, html, stylesheets

I have visual force pages where i have put custom CSS and everything was working fine till yesterday. For eg I have CSS file style.css which i have included at the top my my salesforce page and it has the below code

```
body{
    height:auto;
    width:1038px;
    margin:0 auto
}
```

At initial page load my page is taking the CSS from my style.css file.

Today morning i checked that whenever i re-render some portion of the page, my custom CSS is lost and it gets replaced by salesforce CSS coming from common.css file.

Till yesterday everything was perfectly working. I have not done any changes into my code. Dont know why this is happeneing. Any knowledge ?

**Update:** This issue only happens when my style is in separate static resource. If i paste the CSS into the page directly, then it works fine. But i cannot put the styles into the page.

Comment: Have you tried to use `!important` notation? Like `width:1038px !important;`

Comment: No, I have not used important. I cannot make it important. It happens for most of the elements and I have a very huge style file. The above example was just for illustration. Another case which happens is my button text gets very small

Comment: We notice many errors in a standard SFDC main.js since this morning on all our euro orgs (problems with apex:tab, datepicker,...). 
Seems to be a SFDC bug...

Comment: I am using US org - (cs and na instances)

Comment: @mast0r can u please check if this is happening with syles also ? As mentioned above everything was working fine till yesterday. Even if i rerender anything, my styles were left untouched and my pages were looking perfect

Comment: Nope, only inline edit & date picker.

Comment: how are you including the static resource?  If you are using the salesforce `apex:stylesheet` tag it it might be due to the order in which salesforce outputs the CSS (this would explain why it works inline)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this was salesforce bug which they have fixed. My pages are working fine on cs11 . :)

Comment: I think static resource is not imported successfully, when you put file in static resource. Could you please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important` to override their css.
For eg.

```
body{
    height:auto !important;
    width:1038px !important;
    margin:0 auto !important
}
```

It will override other css and give high priority to your css